# Touchpad and keybroard problems after 16.04.1 installation

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, touchpad, synaptics

My keyboard is very slow to respond and the cursor is jumpy, lagging, and clicks on things randomly when using touchpad. Both keyboard and touchpad worked fine in live USB and for a day after installation. Does anybody know how to fix it? I can't find any info on this.

Also, I have to mention that after three to four hours the touchpad and keyboard start working perfectly without my interference and `xinput --watch-props 12` shows exactly the same output as before. But after every restart the problem reappears.

```
my@toasty-buns:~$ xinput --watch-props 12
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
Device Enabled (139):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (266): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (268):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (269):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (270):  130, 3130, 96, 1697
Synaptics Finger (271): 1, 1, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (272):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (273):   163
Synaptics Tap Durations (274):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (275):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (276):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (277):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (278):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (279): 74, 74
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (280): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (281):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (282): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.053763, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (283):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (284):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (285):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (286): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (287):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (288): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (289):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (290): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (291):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (292): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (293):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (294): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (295):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (296): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (297):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (298):  0
Synaptics Gestures (299):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (300):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (301): 32, 32
Synaptics Area (302):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (303):  1630, 0, 1470, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (304): 18, 18
Device Product ID (259):    2, 14
Device Node (260):  "/dev/input/event5"
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
Synaptics Off (283):    0
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
Synaptics Off (283):    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my battery wasn't functional and after I replaced it the touchpad and keyboard are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because probably you put on the Slow Keys option from System Settings → Universal Access → Typing. Turn it off[image]:

Or try turn-off screen reader.Check it under System Settings → Universal Access → Seeing. Make sure Screen Reader is set to OFF.

---

> *Technology is a way of organizing the universe so that man doesn't have to experience it*

Comment: Thank you for your input, but both Screen Reader and Slow Keys are turned off. I haven't done anything apart from browse on the internet after installing Ubuntu 16.04.1, so I couldn't have put any new options on universal Access. Also, I have to mention that after a couple of hours the keyboard and touchpad start working perfectly without me doing anything.

Comment: So your problem has resolved right?

Comment: No, it didn't. I have the same problem after every restart and then after three hours my touchpad and keyboard are ok.